# Landau-Ginzburg equations and first order phase transitions

Tags: phase-transition

I see there are some similar questions to what I want to ask but what I want to know is not explicitly given. To begin I realize we can use LG equations to describe first order phase transitions ($\phi^4$ theory supports a multi critical point).

My issue is the first order phase transitions are discontinuous and I thought the LG equations are assumed to be a sort of Taylor series expansion around a critical temperature where the order parameter is small; hence, for a continuous phase transition.

I have swept this under the rug for a while, and got to the point that I do not want to ask anyone because maybe I should already know... That's the beauty of these forums I guess!

Comment: You're correct that using a power series in the order parameter isn't really justified in quantitatively studying first-order phase transitions. But since there's no emergent universality in these phase transitions, just using a qualitatively similar model like LG can be illuminating. There are also "weakly first-order transitions," which are first-order transitions where the correlation length does gets very large without diverging (they are "close to" continuous transitions so there are some signatures of universality.)

Comment: Ya it seems rather hand wavy to use here to say the least... Thanks for the reply!